# Filter multiple lists React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

I have 6 lists, each list has an ID that link it to previous list, for example:

```
List 1: [
 {id:1, name: 'list1item1'}, 
 {id:2, name: 'list1item2'}, 
 {id:3, name: 'list1item3'}, 
 {id:4, name: 'list1item4'}, 
]

List 2: [
 {id:1, name: 'list2item1', list1id:3},
 {id:2, name: 'list2item2', list1id:3},  
 {id:3, name: 'list2item3', list1id:4}    
]

List 3: [
 {id:1, name: 'list3item1', list2id:1},
 {id:2, name: 'list3item2', list2id:2},  
 {id:3, name: 'list3item3', list2id:1}    
]
```

each object of each list is an checkbox, by clicking one of it I need to filter previous and next lists by the selected item. For example if I select items with name `list2item1` and `list2item3`, the `List1` must contain `list1item3` and `list1item4` and `List3` must contain `list3item1` and `list3item3`. I tried to do a recursive function, but maybe I wrote it incorrect, because it doesn't filter ok.
What is the best method to do this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is list 1 parent of list 2 and list 2 parent of list 3 and... ? Can you change the structure of your data? Is this like selecting an item in a nested list in a menu or tree structure where you want to select all the ancestors and descendants of the selected items?

Comment: No, each list is independent and doesn't have any parent. This lists represent categories of products, and by checking them, products are filtered. But, for exemple if I select a category from second list, in the first list must remain just categories that are linked with first list

Comment: I'm not sure if I followed, but here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/c0m1t/pen/abmjKMd?editors=0010). The assumption is every list item will only point to its parent, meaning in list number n, there would be a list<n-1>id. I'd suggest you to try a different structure and see if it makes it easier for you or not.